# Low pass filter to maintain edge information

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, gaussian-process

I am looking for a kernel as low pass filter that satisfy as follows:

[image]

In the my reference paper, the author suggest gaussian kernel that is
[image]

The gaussian kernel is very good to approximate that properties. But the kernel reduce edege information when kernel size is big. Could you suggest to me any kernel that can statisfy three above conditions and more robust than gaussian about noise reducing (maintain edge information). I found a kernel as modify kernel. But it very difficult to implement. Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these kernels? It sounds like you either want the pyramid match kernel or the Matern kernel.

Comment: @JacobMick: My work is very simple. Given a image. How to separate that image into small region with center at pixel x. So gaussian kernek K(x) will divide image into small image with size is $\sigma$. Hence, to separate for whole image, we only do convolution. Do you have any kernel can do it